# Не противоречит ли нормам словообразования деепричастие "выкомкивая"?

Tags: словообразование, деепричастия

Пример употребления: больной дрыгает ногами, выкомкивая из-под себя простыню.

Comment: А в чем противоречие?

Comment: @Aer не видел авторитетных примеров употребления

Comment: Нормы словообразования на то и даны, чтобы образовывать не встречающиеся слова :)  А так, сложное для восприятия деепричастие можно заменить двумя более простыми: больной дрыгает ногами, комкая и стягивая ими простыню.

Comment: @user190920 вопрос заключается не в конкретном предложении, а в конкретном деепричастии. Я поясню затруднение. Похожие деепричастия включают чётко направленое движение (выТАСКИВАЯ,выШВЫРИВАЯ, выКЛДЫВАЯ, выТЯГИВАЯ). В моём примере это деепричастие "трансформирования предмета" и по характеру глагола больше похоже на некое "выСКЛАДЫВАЯ". Отсюда вопрос, сочетается ли эта приставка с таким корнем, жизнеспособна ли она, либо есть грубое как нарушение каких-либо принципов словообразования.

Comment: Ах вон оно что. Действительно, основа "комкать" и приставка "вы" не очень сочетаются в большинстве контекстов. Разве что приходит на ум такое смысловое направление: вытворять=выделывать творения, выкомкивать = выделывать комкания

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поначалу я подумала, что это окказионализм, потому что глагол комкать в литературном языке существует только в двух формах - комкать и скомкать, никаких выкомкать, а тем более выкомкивать нет. Потом посмотрела, оказывается, есть, правда, я не поняла, что это - просторечие или диалект, в диалектах такого не встречала. Но вот в произведениях Николая Гайдука встречается.

Николай Гайдук. Праздник белого снега:

> Берёзы, клёны, тополи в кружева обрядились – закуржавели, чтобы не
>   сказать «закружавели». Да, словарь зачастую бледнеет, мельчает перед
>   такой великой красотой, и человек поневоле сбивается на банальности,
>   вот и я начинаю сравнивать весёлых снегирей да свиристелей с
>   коралловыми бусами, качающимися на шеях деревьях. Вот так выдумал,
>   **«выкомкал»**!

https://iknigi.net/avtor-nikolay-gayduk/146034-izbrannoe-nikolay-gayduk/read/page-27.html

У него вообще много таких колоритных слов: ***Выструнив*** шею, косуля взволнованно фыркнула. (Ник.Гайдук. Полынь далёкая.) Возле прясла, где задремывали белые деревья, не успевшие **отлистопадить**, что предвещало нелегкую зиму, косуля наклонилась, зубами подточила красноталовую ветку, торчавшую из сугроба

> Для конька-горбунка. Мам, сошьешь? А, сошьешь? — Отстань! Ты, Егор,
>   **как выкомкаешь чо**... Или делать мне нечего?

https://www.uralstalker.com/uarch/us/1987/09/15/

Вот ещё, даже в стихах:

> Я купил эту маску спьяну,
>
> Не взирая на несуразность,
>
> Деньги **выкомкав** по карманам,
>
> На каком то базаре грязном

http://www.neogranka.com/forum/showthread.php?t=31031

> Набухшие шрамы – дань узам и памяти.
>
> Ты есть, это значит - дышать чаще
>
> И **выкомкать** прошлое грубо руками,
>
> Сделавшись новой (читай «настоящей»).

Без названия, MyLove.Ru
© https://mylove.ru/morea/diary/ya-hotela-objechsya-i-ya-obojglas-rubcami-po-koje-lezviya-vzglyada/

> ...вот такая вот натура еще одного старшего студента университета
>   Кэйо, который вечно держит в руках свое хобби - пластилин, из которого
>   он может **выкомкать** хоть портрет самого папы римского.

http://narucity.rolka.su/viewtopic.php?id=135

С одной стороны, это похоже на авторские неологизмы - каждый со своим значением, а с другой - слова-то все понятны и соответствуют значению приставки ВЫ - 1) исчерпанность действия, достижение чего-то, например, выучить, выдумать, выпросить; 2) движение изнутри (по Ожегову). Эти авторы использовали первое значение приставки - довести действие до конца.

Видимо, глагол выкомкать всё же имеет право на жизнь, не противоречит он правилам словообразования. Ну, а если есть **выкомкать**, вероятно, возможно и **выкомкивать**, по крайней мере, не противоречит правилам словообразования, не грамматическая ошибка, скорее лексическая неожиданность.

Comment: _Толковый cловарь поморьской говори:_ 912. **ВЫкомкать** (гл., сов. в.) — повредить, измять, вытоптать (арх.). https://proza.ru/2018/06/30/1357

Comment: Но в приведённых примерах значение не то, у автора вопроса  - вытаскивая комками.

Comment: Спасибо за обстоятельный ответ. Шикарно

Comment: Тут хоть какое-нибудь общепринятое значение найти - уже хорошо. Если ориентироваться на древний словарь, то можно сказать: Земля здесь вЫкомкана бомбардировками времен второй мировой войны. PS Кстати в некоторых словах допустимы различные ударения изменяющие смысл слова и даже морфологическую категорию. Но наш глагол вроде имеет единственный вариант вЫкомкать.

Answer (score 3):

**Комкать – выкомкать – выкомкивать.**

В словаре можно найти глаголы с разными приставками, а также формы несовершенного вида с суффиксом ИВА, образованные от них, например:

**ИСКОМКАТЬ**,  св. что Разг. Совершенно измять, превратить в комок. И. бумагу.

**ПЕРЕКОМКАТЬ**, св. что. Разг. Скомкать целиком или всё, многое. П. платок. П. всё бельё. П. бумажные деньги. П. что-л. от волнения. Небрежно п. все документы. **Перекомкивать**.

Там нет слова ***выкомкать***, но мне кажется, что  это **народное творчество.** Я даже попыталась найти его в словаре Даля, но не получилось.

Таким образом, с точки зрения словообразования **нормы соблюдены**, но интересное **новшество** есть.

Я полагаю, оно заключается в том, что эта приставка имеет **двойное значение:** (1) **превратить** в комок (сравнить: лепить – вылепить) и (2) **удалить** (сравнить: тащить – вытащить). Это в заданном примере (выкомкать простыню) и выкомкать деньги из кармана, выкомкать прошлое.

А вот выкомкать портрет,   выкомкать (выдумать) что-то – это (1) **превратить** в комок, а потом из комков (2) **создать**, слепить, построить.

**Интересное значение.** Понятен процесс лепки из глины, выкомкать (придумать) – это нафантазировать что-то несуразное.

Во всех примерах подчеркнута **мятость, бесформенность, фрагментарность** как реальной материи, так и мыслей, чувств, воспоминаний.

Поэтому таким **востребованным** оказалось это двойное значение приставки, что видно из литературных примеров.

И еще у меня **возник вопрос**: а у нас вообще-то **существуют** слова с двойными приставками или это совершенно особый случай?

Comment: Спасибо. Это важно. Второй ответ принять не могу. Вам плюс

Comment: Это вам спасибо за интересный вопрос, который сначала было и не заметили, а также за ваше внимание к русскому языку. В наше время, когда нас окружает огромное количество информации,  это особенно ценное качество. (Я немного дополнила свой ответ.)